# Insert values into table by the event handler

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2008

I have connected my local database created by sql server with my project in visual studio (C#). Now I wish to enter the data given in the text field by the user in to my database. Here is what i have tried to do

```
    private void Button_AddCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         try
         {
             //SqlConnection objsqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
             SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SHIRWANIPC;" + 
"Initial Catalog=TEST DATABASE;" + "Integrated Security=True");
             myConnection.Open();
             SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO 
Customer(PhoneNumber,MobileNumber,Address) VALUES (a, b, c)", myConnection);
             objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         catch(SqlException ex)
         {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
         }
     }
```

It throws an exception saying that `invalid column name a,invalid column name b,invalid column name c`.  Whats the problem and how do I get input from the user into my database using insert query ? I am working on visual studio C# and the local database was created by using ms sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
VALUES (a, b, c)
```

with

```
VALUES (' + textBox1.value + (other text area) + ')'
```

Check the input before the query anyway!

Ok

```
SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customer(PhoneNumber,MobileNumber,Address) VALUES ('" + PhoneNumber.Text + "', '" + MobileNumber.Text + "', '" + Address.Text + "')", myConnection);
```

Comment: SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customer(PhoneNumber,MobileNumber,Address) VALUES ('PhoneNumber.Text+ MobileNumber.Text+ Address.Text')", myConnection);

Comment: this is what i did ,still throws the exxception

Comment: Between values add the "," + value

Comment: VALUES ('" + PhoneNumber.Text + "', '" + Address.Text + "')" im from phone but its what you should do

Comment: could you write it down i do not understand it\

Comment: could you write it down i donot inderstand

Comment: Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'text' and no extension method 'text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?  now this error

Comment: Change .text to .Text

Answer (score 0):

You need enclose string types within single quotes.

Try This:

```
INSERT INTO Customer(PhoneNumber,MobileNumber,Address) VALUES ('a','b','c')
```

**Suggestion:** Your query is open to `sql injection attacks` please use `Parameterised queries` to avoid them.

Try This: Using **Parameterised Queries**.

```
    private void Button_AddCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         try
         {
             //SqlConnection objsqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
             SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(
             "Data Source=SHIRWANIPC;" + "Initial Catalog=TEST DATABASE;"
                                            + "Integrated Security=True");
             myConnection.Open();
             SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO 
                   Customer(PhoneNumber,MobileNumber,Address) VALUES   
                  (@phonenumber,@mobilenumber,@address)", myConnection);
            objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phonenumber",TextBox1.Text);
            objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobilenumber",TextBox2.Text);
            objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address",TextBox3.Text);
            objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         catch(SqlException ex)
         {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
         }
     }
```

Comment: after i did this INSERT INTO Customer(PhoneNumber,MobileNumber,Address) VALUES ('a','b','c') it add a b and c as string to my database